# Get the latest version of the data and set it to version 0 and remove all other records, for each day

Tags: perl, bash, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

Table:

```
 Input
Date      Data,   version   identifier
20130909  dsfcat    0 ,         7
20130909  dosdfg    1 ,         7
20130909  dsdfog    0 ,         8
20130909  dsdfog    3 ,         8
20130910  afsdfds   0 ,         8
130910    afsdfds    2 ,         8
```

```
 Output
Date      Data,   version   identifier
20130909  dosdfg    0 ,        7
20130909  dsdfog    0 ,        8
20130910  afsdfds   0,         8
```

1. I have a table that stores multiple version of the data for each day.
2. Each data doesn't need need to have all the versions.  primary key is date, identifier, version

Goal: for each identifier (can be comprised of multiple rows) for each date, set max version to 0 and remove all other records.

I am trying to avoid using  joins.  I can supplement it with perl, bash scripting

EDIT:1. perhaps I can remove all the values that are not of the highest version and then set eights version to 0.

Comment: does this solve your problem? `awk '$3==0' file` ? (without the header) if you want header `awk 'NR==1||$3==0' file`

Comment: It is stored in database....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done purely through SQL:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tbl;
20130909|dsfcat|0|7
20130909|dosdfg|1|7
20130909|dsdfog|0|8
20130909|dsdfog|3|8
20130910|afsdfds|0|8
20130910|afsdfds|2|8

sqlite> DELETE FROM
   ...>   tbl
   ...> WHERE
   ...>   Date||':'||identifier||':'||version NOT IN (
   ...>     SELECT
   ...>       Date||':'||identifier||':'||version
   ...>     FROM
   ...>       tbl
   ...>     GROUP BY
   ...>       identifier,Date
   ...>     HAVING
   ...>       version=MAX(version)
   ...>   );
sqlite> UPDATE tbl SET version=0;

sqlite> SELECT * FROM tbl;
20130909|dosdfg|0|7
20130909|dsdfog|0|8
20130910|afsdfds|0|8
```

What this does is delete all records where their key fields do *NOT* match a list of keys that are associated with the records containing the highest version number per identifier/date, then it updates the remaining records to have a version number of 0.

Additional suggestions:

1. I don't know how big this database is going to be, but you might want to add a "processed" field that indicates whether a given record has been through the daily pruning process or not; otherwise the set of data the query runs through will always contain already-processed records which will grow over time.
2. If you changed your current primary key definition to a unique index and then added a single primary key field (Such as an auto incrementing number) it would free the query from needing to concatenate all the key fields together in the `DELETE` and sub-`SELECT`.

Comment: How would you modify it if you wanted for a specific date? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code do what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "data.in" or die "$!";

my %table;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($date, $data, $version, $identifier) = split;

    if (not defined $table{$date}{$identifier}{version}
            or $table{$date}{$identifier}{version} < $version) {
        $table{$date}{$identifier}{version} = $version;
        $table{$date}{$identifier}{data} = $data;
    }
}

close $fh;

foreach my $date (sort keys %table) {
    foreach my $identifier (sort keys $table{$date}) {
        my $data = $table{$date}{$identifier}{data};
        $table{$date}{$identifier}{version} = 0;
        my $version = $table{$date}{$identifier}{version};
        print "$date\t$data\t$version\t$identifier\n";
    }
}
```

If you want to remove all the records except for the ones that are stored in the hash, I think you can do something like

```
my $query = "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE date = $date AND identifier = $identifier AND data != $data";
```

inside the inner `foreach` loop. However, I haven't tested this so I'm not sure if it works.